# Failed to use the checked attribute with <select multiple></select>

Tags: html

I waned to use the checked attribute with a `<select multiple></select>` but the checked attribute didn't work.
I don't know what I did wrong

```
<body>
<form action="" method="get">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="skill">Skill</label>
        <select name="skills" id="skill" multiple>
            <option checked value="html">Html</option>
            <option value="css">Css</option>
            <option value="jss">Javascript</option>
        </select>
        <br>
        <input type="submit">
        <input type="reset">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image: The output in the browser]

Thank you

Comment: Please include code, not images of code. Preferably as an [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<option checked>` should be `<option selected>`, as this is an option, not a checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in order to work

```
    <form action="/">
  <label for="skills">Skill</label>
  <select name="skills" id="skills" multiple>
    <option value="volvo">Html</option>
    <option value="Css">Css</option>
    <option value="Javascript">Javascript</option>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Hold down the Ctrl (windows) or Command (Mac) button to select multiple options.